# Variable heights in linearlayout android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I like to get the following:
I want the scroll view to be always 50% or bigger on the top.. This according to the listview at the bottom. The listview will be max 50% according to the amount of items that it has.

Does somebody know how to get this?
I have been trying some things with layout_width/height and weights.. but can't come to a solution.. neither have found a solution on stackoverflow..

the basic setup:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".RouteGroupDetailActivity" >

    <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all - it's pretty weird requirement, but if you want to proceed with it - I would put layout_height="match_parent" on both ScrollView and ListView and layout_weight="1" on ListView. If you have more than X items in the ListView just add layout_weight="1" on ScrollView programaticaly.

Comment: When i remove the layout_weight i don't see the listview anymore...

Comment: that's because you have added match_parent to ScrollView. If you want simpler way just put layout_height="match_parent" & layout_weight="1" to both elements. You can programatically change either layout_weight to have one element take more space.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But i wait a while for if someone knows a way without calculating the height of the list view. It needs to be possible. And about the weird requirements. It would be a lot easier if clients don't ask weird things.

Comment: @kape123 can you post your anwser to do it programatically? after all it was the easiest way to do it.. and i like to accept it.